# Identification of component

Tags: power-supply, identification, thermistor

I was desoldering components from a power supply board for a printer and I came across this small component. It was pressed against a heat sink so I assume it is some sort of thermistor but I am not sure.
The text on the component is "5104BL6"
[image]

[image]

Comment: A detonator....

Comment: That is a thermistor. It's a temperature sensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### It's a temp sensor for laser printers.

Between then electrode stiff wires is an **SMD Thermistor** which is used in Laser printers to regulate drum heater temperature so that when carbon is attracted to the charges on the photosensitive cartridge and transferred to the hot drum the carbon then fuses into the paper.

The high temp Kapton®  or Polyimide package withstands solder temperatures and protects the sensor from carbon getting stuck to it while and the leads from getting spread apart causing stress on the electrical joints.  The tip helps regulate the drum temperature and the heater often peaks On at 1500W with a low duty cycle at temperature is reached in a minute or so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a thermistor.  That's a resistor that deliberately and predictably changes resistance as a function of temperature.

Being on a heat sink makes sense.  Something is probably measuring the heat sink temperature, and either alarming or shutting things down if it gets too hot.

The other possibility is a thermocouple, but it seems not so be because:

There seems to be a dark blob of material at the tip between the two electrodes.  Thermocouples are just the two electrodes directly touching each other.

Thermocouples require two dissimilar materials.  It appears the two leads are of the same material.

Most thermocouple materials don't solder well.  It looks like the legs have solder on them.  They were possibly soldered directly to the PCB.

Comment: I would replace the word 'deliberately' with 'predictably'

Comment: @vicat: All resistors change resistance as a function of temperature.  I wanted to point out that in this case, that's actually the purpose.  However, I added "predictably".